# Optimise a MySQL query that uses IN and MAX(date)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that returns the latest datetime for each CustomerID from a table named 'customers'. There are many different CustomerID entries in the table, and many rows with the same CustomerID but with different datetime entries. I have been using the query below that returns one row per unique CustomerID and the latest (MAX) date for that CustomerID. The table has about 6000 rows.

The customers table:

```
CustLogID (Primary key, INT 11)
CustomerID (INT 11)
DateTime (DATETIME)
```

The query:

```
SELECT
CustomerID AS custid,
DateTime AS latestdatetime
FROM customers WHERE DateTime IN (
SELECT MAX( DateTime )
FROM customers GROUP BY CustomerID
)
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

The trouble I'm having is that on my development machine with a local MySQL DB it returns the results (About 1500 rows) in under a second, but on my web host it times out never completing the task, same PHP script, same database data with the DB being located on the web host server. All other scripts on the web host run fine, and some of these are quite complex too.

If anyone knows why this query is causing such a bottleneck or can refactor it I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No point in using `IN` or `JOIN`, this problem can be simply solved with:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID custid,
    MAX(DateTime) latestdatetime
FROM customers
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Comment: To Havenard. I tried that previously but it did not return the latest datetime as expected. I'll try it again anyway to see if that works. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Hevenard.. I tried your query and it worked! Strange thing is I did try a similar query previously and the DateTime results returned were not the latest ones. Thank for your help. :-)

Comment: @user2783034 Probably you forgot to use `GROUP BY`, without this the result of `MAX` will change from the highest date per customer, to the highest date present in the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not doing what you expect.  It is returning any customer that has a `datetime` value that matches the last datetime for any other customer in the table.  So, the query could return multiple rows for a single customer, where each row has a `datetime` value matches some other customer.

I am also going to assume that you actually want the most recent row for each customer *and* that you want other columns.  Otherwise, a simple `group by` is sufficient (basically your subquery).

One fix is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE c.DateTime = (SELECT MAX(c2.DateTime )
                    FROM customers c2
                    WHERE c2.CustomerID = c.CustomerId
                   )
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

For performance, you want an index on `customers(CustomerId, DateTime)`.

Comment: To Gordon. I did run a query that displayed all the datetime entries for a specific customerID and checked that the latest date shown was the same as the one returned in the query in my original question and it was.  Anyway, I'll try your query as see how that goes, thank you. One thing, the index on 'customers(CustomerId, DateTime)' you mentioned. Do you mean that the field CustomerID should be the primary key? As CustLogID is the primary key since this contains unique values (Increments on each row) unlike CustomerID that can have multiple rows each with the same CustomerID.

Comment: @user2783034 . . . No, I mean that a composite index should be created on those two columns.

Comment: I tried your query and it timed out on Heidi SQL on my local machine so it performed worse than my original one. I didn't try it on my web host and I didn't create a composite index, but thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: @user2783034 . . . Did you create the composite index?

Comment: No I did not but I'm happy with Havenard's query so I won't be doing that. Thanks again.